# Why does representation theory often arise in the context of quantum algorithms for the hidden subgroup problem?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, mathematics, resource-request, hidden-subgroup-problem

I noticed that approaches for finding quantum algorithms the hidden subgroup problem for both Abelian groups ($(\Bbb Z_n\times \Bbb Z_n, +)$, $(\Bbb R, +)$, etc.) and non-Abelian finite groups like the dihedral group and symmetric group often use [representation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory).

1. Why is this the case? How's it helpful?
2. What are some resources for where I can learn sufficient representation theory to at least get started with understanding such algorithms? (I'm not in a position to read a heavy grad-level math textbook on representation theory.)

Comment: To 1: Basically because these problems are about group theory but Quantum mechanics (in the standard formulation) is built around vector spaces. How can you connect these two algebraic objects: via representations which map group elements to matrices (or linear maps if you want). To be more precise: the construction often involves labelling the basis states by group elements as $|g\rangle$. Then you need a representation of the group to actually act with another group element $g'$ on this state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two classical texts for the representation theory of finite groups are the books of [Hamermesh](https://books.google.co.il/books?hl=en&lr=&id=w6PDAgAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PR13&dq=Hamermesh%20group%20theory&ots=KyJzwkFwpd&sig=AhIw_k1bib1lg7g1wA_pLNBeqKc&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Hamermesh%20group%20theory&f=false)  and [Serre](https://books.google.co.il/books?hl=en&lr=&id=9mT1BwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA3&ots=hS5zMhyfmp&sig=rf3o5UcnJEHt1s9DSEgJ6jwRJc4&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false). These books however lack chapters on Fourier analysis needed for the quantum computation applications.

For a more modern text for finite group representations which includes a chapter on Fourier analysis, please see the lecture notes by: [Steinberg](http://users.metu.edu.tr/sozkap/513-2013/Steinberg.pdf).

However, for a fast introduction, quite sufficient for the quantum computation applications, there are very concise texts: in [Enrique Alvarez lecture notes](https://members.ift.uam-csic.es/ealvarez/amm.pdf) (Chapter 9, in first reading one can skip the representation theory of $S_N$ and  study the 17 pages 79-95 only), and in chapter 2 of the [lecture notes](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~wilthoma/rep_theory/master.pdf) by Willwacher.

Since these concise resources also lack the subject of Fourier analysis, you can read the 5 pages of  chapter 3 of [Shengyu Zhang](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~syzhang/course/QC13/) quantum computing course giving an introduction to the group theory needed for the hidden subgroup problem.

In the hidden subgroup problem, we are given a function $f: G \rightarrow S$ ($S$ is a finite set) which is invariant on the cosets of some subgroup $H$ of $G$; i.e., $f(g) = f(gh), \,\, h\in H$; and we want to identify the subgroup $H$.

Representation theory appears because every function on a finite group $G$ can be written as a linear combination of the matrix elements of its irreducible representations; and we need to identify the representations appearing in the function $f$. We do so by preparing a state:
$$\sum_G |g, f(g)\rangle$$
(This state is efficiently preparable, when there is an efficient oracle for the computation of $f$). If we measure the second register, we are left with a uniformly weighted combination of group elements belonging to the coset corresponding to the measured values of $f$:
$$\sum_H |ch\rangle$$
($c$ is any element in this coset).

Let $\rho$ be an irreducible representation of $G$, then $\rho$ is a matrix function of $G$ of dimension $d_{\rho} \times d_{\rho}$; the quantum Fourier transform, transforms a group vector $|g\rangle$ to:

$$\sum_{\rho \in \hat{G}} \sum_{i=1}^{d_{\rho}}\sum_{j=1}^{d_{\rho}}\sqrt{\frac{d_{\rho}}{|G|}} \rho(g)_{ij} |i, j, \rho\rangle$$

Where $\hat{G}$ is the set of irreducible representations, (which is in a one to one correspondence with the conjugacy classes of $G$).

In order to appreciate the role of the Fourier transform, please consider the case of $\mathbb{Z}_N =  \{ z_0, …, z_{N-1}\}$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_N$ is Abelian all its irreducible representations are one dimensional given by:

$$\rho_m (z_n) = e^{\frac{2 \pi i mn}{N}}$$

This is the kernel of the usual Fourier transform. $m$ is the representation index and $n$ is the group element index. We know that if we perform a Fourier transform of the function $\rho_m$, we get a peaked function at $m$ by which we identifiy the representation $m$.

In the general case when we measure the $\rho$ register in  $|i, j, \rho\rangle$, we get with a high probability a representation appearing in $f$, thus by repeating the experiment, we get with a high probability all representations having $H$ in their kernel and we can identify $H$ as their mutual kernel.

Please see the following https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.0380v1  work by Childs and Dam reviewing cases where the above standard method and other improved methods lead to efficient hidden subgroup identification in the non-Abelian cases.