# Status of hidden shift and hidden subgroup problems

Tags: quantum-algorithms, hidden-subgroup-problem

We know that solving a hidden subgroup problem over a non-commutative group is a long standing problem in quantum computing even for groups like $D_{2n}$ (alternatively can be written as $\mathbb{Z}_n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$) for general $n$.   What are some families $n$ for which this can be done?

Comment: Good question; I was thinking of asking this myself! You might be interested in Greg Kuperberg's [2003 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0302112) which presents a $\mathcal{O}(\exp(\sqrt {C \log N}))$ quantum algorithm for the dihedral subgroup. Note that it is pretty math-heavy and uses representation theory (something that I've been [attempting to learn myself](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8912/why-does-representation-theory-often-arise-in-the-context-of-quantum-algorithms)).

Comment: I think that is for arbitrary Dihedral group. What I am looking  at is some sense, auxiliary problem. This is subexponential algorithm for an arbitrary case. I wanted to know about a special case underlying a polynomial algorithm.

Comment: I understand; I'm not aware of those special cases as such but [this](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?pid=S2179-84512017000200215&script=sci_abstract) and [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0102014)  seem to be some such.

Comment: Greg recently gave a talk, which includes the most recent results in this area  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdUiO78bVdI